# Hibernate JDBC Driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver could not be loaded

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc

I'm trying to run this simple hibernate example: 
[tutorial link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_examples.htm)

Error is

> Specified JDBC Driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver could not be loaded

[image]

here is an error stacktrace:

[image]

Comment: classpath or servlet container setup issue for these error msgs. It is needing `mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin` jar or one of its siblings

Comment: It looks like the .jar file is in the root folder of the project. Perhaps it should be under "External Libraries"? (I've never used IntelliJ, but in Eclipse it would need to be in the "Referenced Libraries" folder, a.k.a. the classpath for the project.)

Comment: Please, [do not upload images of code/data/error](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add **mysql-connector-java-5.1.x-bin.jar** not mysql-connector-java-5.1.x.jar.

Also, Add it to the global lib directory. For Tomcat this is `TOMCAT_HOME/lib`.

1. Click File from File menu
2. Project Structure (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> on Windows/Linux, <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd> on Mac OS X)
3. Select Modules at the left panel
4. Dependencies tab
5. Add... → Project Library →  Attach Jar

Try this.

Comment: I've just added mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar and get the same exception

Comment: Dear  K K, I've just edited my question adding an error stacktrace pic.

Comment: My answer is the only solution. You have to cross check whether jar is in correct folder or not. Add in project lib directory & tomcat lib.

Comment: @Mary i have edited my answer. make sure you have jar in external lib

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what is different about the `bin` version of that JAR.

Answer (score 0):

If you got maven support with your project, you can also add this dependency to your POM:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>mysql</groupId>
<artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
<version>(current version)</version>
```

Please also notice you might want to update the scope of your dependency if you deploy it.

Answer (score 0):

To overcome from this issue, need to add hibernate manually to intalij(IDE)

1. download hibernate orm dependency jar file
2. open -> lib -> required ->copy the files
3. paste it in intalij(IDE)
4. 

Click File from File menu
Project Structure
Select Libraries at the left panel
Dependencies tab
Add... → Project Library → Attach Jar